# problem getting customer detail by email

Tags: email

when i write below code

```
$email=$recipient['email'];
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
->loadByEmail($email);
```

i get error entity value can be null why so what should i write there

what should i write to make it work, i had already set share customer to global but stilll same error message

Answer (score 0):

The section of code you share is correct, however I don't know the value if any of `$recipient['email']` so for testing try hardcoding the email

```
$customer_email = "customer@example.com"; 
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer"); 
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId()); 
$customer->loadByEmail($customer_email); //load customer by email id 

if($customer->getId){
   // do your logic here
}
```